# Retention of users on an Ott platform

Tags: mysql, sql, data-science

I have table called user_info

It has two columns:

```
User_id
Date
```

How do I get to the table like the one mentioned below:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
Date        |total_number_of_users | D2    |D5  |  D7 |   D14|
--------------------------------------------------------------
2020-07-01      1000                 700    500   200    150
2020-07-02      400                  300    250   200    100
```

For example consider the first row in the table I am trying to achieve:

```
total_number_of_users = Total number of users who have visited the site on 2020-07- 01
```

D2=Out of total users who visited the site on 2020-07-01, visited on 2020-07-2

```
D7=Out of total users who visited the site on 2020-07-01, visited on 2020-07-7
```

I have tried the following, how do I get the exact the solution:

```
SELECT user_id, week(login_date) AS login_week
    FROM user_info
    GROUP BY user_id,week(login_date);
SELECT user_id, min(week(login_date)) AS first_week
       FROM user_info
       GROUP BY user_id;
select a.user_id,a.login_week,b.first_week as first_week  from   
              (SELECT
                user_id,
                week(login_date) AS login_week
                FROM user_info
                GROUP BY user_id,week(login_date)) a,
              (SELECT
                user_id,
                min(week(login_date)) AS first_week
                FROM user_info
                GROUP BY user_id) b
        where a.user_id=b.user_id;
```

Comment: (1) Which version of MySQL are you running? (2) What if a user visits the site twice in a day, do you count that twice or once? (3) Actual sample data and corresponding desired results would help clarifying your question.

Comment: 1) I am using , MySQL Workbench 8.0.21 2) if a user visits the site twice in a day, it is still counted as once.

Answer (score 2):

This seems painful, but you can use a self-join and aggregation:

```
select t.date,
       sum( t2.date = t.date) as total_number_of_users,
       sum( t2.date = t.date + interval 1 day ) as d2,
       sum( t2.date = t.date + interval 4 day ) as d5,
       sum( t2.date = t.date + interval 6 day ) as d7,
       sum( t2.date = t.date + interval 13 day ) as d14
from (select distinct date, user_id
      from t
     ) t1 left join
     (select distinct date, user_id
      from t
     ) t2
     on t1.user_id = t2.user_id and
        t2.date in (t1.date, t1.date + interval 1 day, t1.date + interval 4 day, t1.day + interval 6 day, t1.day + interval 13 day)
group by t.date;
```